# How to scale UIImage to fit dimensions of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, scale

I have a UIImage of dimensions 300x600 (height x width). UIImage's relative hierarchy is like so :

[image]

Using AutoLayout, I have set the following constraints for the UIImageView, UIScrollView and UIVIew:

[image]

I have set relative height dimensions of the TableView as follows:

```
// Setting Last Row to height = 70 pixels and first row to fill balance of screen:
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 { return 70 }
    else { return tableView.frame.size.height - 70 }
}
```

What I would like is for the **height** of the UIImage to exactly match the height of the UISCrollView that it sits in. I am not concerned about the eventual width of the UIImage, but would like it to follow confines of 'AspectFit'. So I would probably employ

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

... probably in

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

I would set the dynamic height and width parameters of the UIScrollView, and then set the UIImage height to follow the height of the UISCrollView and allow the `ScaleAspectFit`to automatically handle the width.

I have tried various renditions of code to achieve this, but have failed to achieve the desired result.

**Question:** Am I on the right track? Can anyone kindly get me started with some skeleton code so I can customise it to my needs.

***Side Note:*** I am only allowing for portrait mode of my app. No landscape.

Many thanks in advance for your kind attention and time ;)

Comment: Don't know if I understood it correctly, going with the question I would make a container `UIView` to hold the exact `UIScrollView`then I can create constraints of scroll view's child `UIImageView` to that of the container view i.e. equal heights.

Comment: These constraint are to their parents I suppose like `UIView` <--> `UIScrollView` <--> `UIImageView` but try constraint as `UIView` <--> `UIImageView`

Comment: Hi. Great thought. I have added equal heights constraint (from child `UIImageView` to the container `UIView`) and also changed view -> mode of `UIImageView` in IB to 'Aspect Fill'. Now the height is perfect, but the width is shortened to the left and right of the `UIImageView`.

Comment: 'AspectFill' crops your image to fit in the image view, may be this link help to understand and reach a solution [http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-handling-in-ios/](http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-handling-in-ios/)

Comment: Eureka!! I selected 'Aspect Ratio' for constraint of child `UIImageView` in IB and now the image (`UIImageView`) is scaled perfectly!

Comment: I think the combination of 'Aspect Fill' and 'Aspect Ratio' avoided the effective cropping of my image. Thanks for the link. I will read up a lot more on the area.

Comment: xD lol, happy to help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111739/discussion-between-katherine-jenkins-and-sargeras).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a container `UIView` to hold the exact `UIScrollView` then I can create constraints of scroll view's child `UIImageView` to that of the container view i.e. equal heights.

As I suppose, these constraints are to their parents like

```
UIView <--> UIScrollView <--> UIImageView
```

but try them as

```
UIView <--> UIImageView
```